# Adding PasswordAuthenticator to a Docker instance does not enable authentication

Tags: docker, cassandra, cqlsh

I have a docker compose file with a cassandra container. As default, I can manage the database anonymously because of AllowAllAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml, I want to have PasswordAuthenticator. That's my docker compose:

```
cassandra:
    image: cassandra:4.1
    container_name:  "cassdb"
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassclus
```

I tried copying the file outside the container, editing it and sending it back and restarting container.

I have also tried to copy it outside the container, editing it and creating a volume with it in order to load it on docker compose up:

```
  - ./cassandra.yaml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

In both cases, I get that error whenever doing cqlsh or cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra from inside the container (which I didn't have before):

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', \
  {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, \
  "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. \
  Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I have even tried to add the container with the volume but doing no change to the .yaml I have imported from the container, so I don't think it is related with the PasswordAuthenticator value itself, but with the whole file.

My host machine is a Windows and I am editing the file with Visual Studio Code, I don't know if that may have anything to do.

Comment: SOLVED: I wasn't patient enough, works fine but just needed a few minutes to the rebuild the entire container environment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue keeps coming up so I'm posting here for those that come across this in the future.

---

The connection error returned by cqlsh is almost always one of two things:

1. the node is down, or
2. Cassandra is not listening for client connections on the IP/port.

In this case, it's point (1) because the operator did not wait long enough for the Cassandra instance to come up.

A note to operators: reviewing the Cassandra logs should be your first step when troubleshooting an issue. Even when deployed in a Docker container, Cassandra still needs to go through its startup sequence and it is not instantaneous. Cheers!